# Form not going to route in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an update form that is supposed to go to a route and then the Update function of a controller.  The form is not hitting the route and everything looks right.  I am getting a 404.

I have the following in my routes:

```php
Route::resource('active-plans/basicinfo', 'active_plans\CurrentPlanBasicInfoController');
```

I have the following in my form:

```
<form action='active-plans/basicinfo/{{ $activeplan->id }}' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

  @csrf   
  @method('PATCH')

    ....FORM INPUTS....

   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col text-left">
         <button type="submit" name="action" value="save_and_close" class="btn btn-info">Save and Close</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col text-right">
         <button type="submit" name="action" value="next_step" class="btn btn-info">Next Step</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I have the following in my controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\active_plans;

class CurrentPlanBasicInfoController extends Controller
```

Also, my route helper seems to be working in one spot but not the other.  I have the following working:

Route:

```
Route::resource ('census', 'plan_builder\CensusController');
```

Route Helper in Controller:

```
return redirect()->route('census.edit',$id);
```

This is not working:

Route:

```
Route::resource ('active-plans/basicinfo', 'active_plans\CurrentPlanBasicInfoController');
```

Route Helper in Controller:

```
return redirect()->route('active-plans/add-employees.edit',$id);
```

I imagine I could just name the routes but I'm interested to know why the second version is breaking

Comment: you should not be using relative URLs ... use one of the many URL helpers to generate an absolute URL to where you need the form to go to

Comment: What does it show when you run php artisan route:list ?

Comment: thanks, i had an absolute route.  i tried a route helper in my controller and this works in other parts of my project but not here.  when  i use this:   return redirect()->route('active-plans/add-employees.edit',$id);  with this route: Route::resource ('active-plans/add-employees', 'active_plans\AddEmployeesController'); it says the route is undefined

Comment: in the form ... the form action is a relative path

Comment: I think update should be called as PUT/PATCH, not POST.

Comment: yes, thanks i did fix that.  but i also have this problem in my controller now.

Comment: the controller that doesn't have any code ... update your question with the code, not in the comments

Comment: there is no route with the **name** `'active-plans/add-employees.edit'` that is why ... `Route::resource` registers the routes with specific names, use `php artisan route:list` to see your routes

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Route](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-route) Helpers

```
<form action="{{ route( 'basicinfo.update', $activeplan ) }}" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```